# Spring Boot - how to test Constraint Validation annotations and omit one custom validator (annotation)?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I found several answers on similar problem in Internet but not exactly to my problem. I want to test such a Dto:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SearchDto {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("street")
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String street;

    @JsonProperty("number")
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String number;

    @JsonProperty("locality")
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String locality;

    @JsonProperty("postal_code")
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String postalCode;

    @JsonProperty("city")
    @ValidCity
    @Size(max = 50)
    private String city;
}
```

My test:

```
class SearchDtoAnnotationValidatorsTest {

    protected static Validator validator;
    private ValidatorFactory factory;
    @InjectMocks
    private ValidCountryValidator validCountryValidator;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() {
        if (factory != null) {
            factory.close();
        }
    }

@Test
    void shouldReturnViolationWhenNameIsGreaterThan50Chars() {
        //given
        SearchDto searchDto = SearchDto.builder()
                .name("name dkejdeodejdoewjdowed jeiod jeidj eiodjweiodjeiodjeiodjeoidjeoijdioe jdo")
                .city("country")
                .number("number")
                .locality("locality")
                .street("street")
                .postalCode("54-222")
                .build();

        //when
        Set<ConstraintViolation<SearchDto>> validate = validator.validate(searchDto);

        //then
        assertThat(validate).hasSize(1);
        assertThat(validate.iterator().next().getMessage()).isEqualTo("name must not be greater than 50");
    }
```

I get the error:

```
jakarta.validation.ValidationException: HV000064: Unable to instantiate ConstraintValidator: validator.ValidCityValidator.
```

How to omit `@ValidCity` annotation? I have another test for it.